# Bigcommerce API 404 error on previously working stores with SingleClick App

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, bigcommerce

I am trying to connect to existing stores via the Bigcommerce API that installed my SingleClick App.
For example - the store api: https: //api.bigcommerce.com/stores//v2/store

These are stores I previously connected to and received information, specifically for the "store" function above.
On some stores, I suddenly start to receive a 404 error.
Going over the docs (and experiencing it myself) - I know that if a store owner "uninstalls" my app, I receive a 401 (unauthorized) error.
But now I started receiving a 404 on some accounts and I don't know if it's due to a user uninstalling my app, or something else (maybe the user recreated api keys, changed store credentials or something else)?

Answer (score 0):

I just read over their docs (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/status-codes) and indeed, the 404 is likely being caused because that resource no longer exists, at least in the context of the scope of your OAuth client ID. It's not an access issue (401/403). You can recreate the 404 by passing in a random store hash.